# Django redirect after logout

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django and to authenticate my user, I have a custom OAuth2 provider. I had to write the login and logout view myself because they are doing some very specific things.

I would like to be redirected to the same url after logout. If you are on a page that require to be authenticated, I would like to redirect to the homepage. I didn't find any resource to know if a view/endpoint is using the decorator `login_required`

Answer (score 0):

The [`login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator takes a parameter to redirect users. You could use this.

As of Django 1.9, you could also use the [`AccessMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#redirecting-unauthorized-requests-in-class-based-views).

Unless I misunderstand your question, all the information you need is in the docs. Are you using an older version of Django?

Comment: I'm using 1.8 and I want to redirect after a logout to the same URL. If this particular URL need authentication, then I will have an infinite loop, so I would need to redirect to `/` instead

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just use query string parameter `next`, e.g.:

```
<a href="{% url 'users:user_logout' %}?next={% url 'some_url' %}">Log out</a>
```

The rest is only a matter of arranging template hierarchy, so you will use different urls in different templates without repetition.

Comment: Let's say next url require to be authenticate. Django will automatically redirect to login, I will automatically be authenticate from my provider, and back to this URL. The next parameters in URL would only works if the target page doesn't need authentication.

Comment: Then add middleware class which checks if user is trying to access URL which requires  authentication and redirects to homepage if condition is not satisfied.

Comment: That's the same thing as setting `/` for `LOGIN_URL` I just want to avoid this redirect **after** the user visit the logout page. The best solution would be to know if a path requires login.

Answer (score 0):

in settings.py add this line:

```
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'some_url'
```